# Not possible to search for umlaute in LaTeX

Tags: pdftex, pdf, copy-paste

I am using `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` so I am able write umlaute inside the tex file, but I can't search for a word that contains umlaute inside the compiled pdf. 
Is this a "bug" inside LaTeX or do I have to change something in my tex file?
If I copy a word that contains a umlaut like `wähle` this: "W ̈ ahle" appears in my clipbox.

Comment: Add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks! Is there a way to copy things out of math mode?
(`V \backslash \{v\}`) looks like: "V ztsu" after copying :/

Comment: A general comment: You should probably write `V \setminus \{v\}` in order to get better spacing around the "backslash" character.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.